# Prolog - Modifying and returning list

Tags: list, prolog, return

I want to define predicate which takes a list, adds an element to the list, let's say the number "1", and then returns the list.

I've found out I can add elements to a list using append/3, but I want to use in inside another predicate, thus why I want it to return "my modified list".

My object-oriented mindset tells me to ask the interpreter something like: ?-append(X,5,X). , so that it takes the list X, adds 5 to it, and returns "the new X", but I know that's not how unification works, so my mind is kinda in a glitch.

Can anyone please try to explain how something like this could be achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already very close to the solution, so I only rephrase what you are beginning to sense already:

First, you **cannot modify** a list in pure Prolog.

Instead, you should think in terms of **relations** between entities. In your case, think in terms of *relations between lists*.

So, "adding the number 1" to a list is a *relation* between two lists, which could look like this:

```
list_with_one(Ls, [1|Ls]).
```

Note that this works in *all* directions! You can use it to:

- **generate** answers
- **test** particular cases
- "reverse" the direction etc.

So, all you need to do in your case is to think in terms of *relations between lists*: One without an element, and how this relates to a different list *with* the element.

Obviously, these two lists will be indicated by *different variables* and **different arguments**.

Note in particular that `append(X, 5, X)` *cannot hold*: First of all, `append/3` is meant to be a relation between **lists**, and `5` is *not* a list. Second, assuming you wrote for example `append(Xs, [5], Xs)`, then this would be true *if* there where a list `Xs` such that if the element `5` were appended to `Xs`, the resulting list would again be `Xs`. Good luck finding such a list... Note also the naming convention to denote lists by letting the variable name end with an *s*.

It is also falls a bit short to blame this on your "object-oriented mindset", since you can have object oriented programming in Prolog too.

Answer (score 0):

Although lists in Prolog cannot be modified, it is possible to add elements to the end of [a list with an unspecified length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48635008/975097). In this way, items can be "appended" to a list without creating another list:

```
:- initialization(main).

append_to_list(List,Item) :-
    append_to_list(List,Item,0).

append_to_list(List,Item,Index) :-
    % using SWI-Prolog's nth0 predicate
    (nth0(Index,List,Check_Item),
    var(Check_Item),
    nth0(Index,List,Item));
    (Next_Index is Index+1,
    append_to_list(List,Item,Next_Index)).

main :-
    A = [1,2,3|_],
    append_to_list(A,4),
    append_to_list(A,7),
    writeln(A).
```

In this example, `A` becomes `[1,2,3,4,7|_]`.